# Getting only day and month from a date field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of dates that are in the format DD-MMM-YYYY. I need to be able to compare dates by using only the DD-MMM part of the date, since the year isn't important.

How would I achieve this?

I have tried reading up on the DATEPART function (edit: which evidently wouldn't work) but I can only theoretically get that to return either the DD or the MMM parts, not both of them at once.

Edit: added oracle tag. Sorry.

Example of date field: 01-MAR-1994

Comment: Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL? What's the **data type** of the column?

Comment: @neoistheone I think DATEPART is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Using oracle. What I meant by 'using' was that I tried to understand it. Sorry for not specifying. The data type of the column is of type Date.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Extract` function http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your column is of type `DATE` then it doesn't have a format.

If I understand you right, then you want to view the `mon-dd` part only, so you need to convert it with `TO_CHAR` function,
i.e.:

```
select to_char(your_date_column, 'mon-dd') from your_table
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks. Can I compare the dates normally with the to_char function? For example where mar-01 > apr-30

Comment: @rakeshisu, No... it's a string now not a date. Maybe you need a different format, something like `select to_char(your_date_column, mmdd`) (remember the date doesn't have a format it's a number representing the date)

Comment: Oh ok I see. So when using the to_char function, what specifies the datatype that will be returned, or does it always return a string?

Comment: Always a string (as it is called *to char*)

Answer (score 8):

Convert your dates using the following format, it will only month and the date part. You have to replace getdate() with you date fields.:

```
  select convert(varchar(5),getdate(),110)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server or Oracle since you attempted using DATEPART, you can just get the day and month using the `DAY()` and `MONTH()` functions. Assuming, again, that the dates you are comparing are in two different tables, it would look similar to this:

```
SELECT MONTH(t1.date), DAY(t2.date)
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE MONTH(t1.date) = MONTH(t2.date)
AND DAY(t1.date) = DAY(t2.date)
```

EDIT: If you are just comparing rows in the same table, you only need a very simple query.

SQLFiddle

```
select id, TO_CHAR(most_recent, 'mon-dd')
from (
    select id, MAX(date1) AS most_recent
    from table1
    group by id
  )
```

Comment: I am comparing different rows in the same table. Trying to determine which of the records occurred the latest in any given year. When I attempt to use either the DAY() or MONTH() functions it gives me an invalid identifier error.

Comment: To do that you just need to do a subquery that gets the max date, then select that in 'mm-dd' format in your outer select statement using `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score 4):

`select FORMAT(yourcoulmn_name, 'dd/MM') from table`

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine month and day into one integer:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datecol) * 100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM datecol) AS MonthDay
```

Then it's easier to sort and compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$m = date("m");//Month

$d = date("d");//Day

$sql = "SELECT * FROM contactdata WHERE MONTH(date) = '$m' AND DAY(date) = '$d' ";
```

only checks day and month and returns today, day and month from database

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
`select CONVERT(varchar(7),datetime_column,100) from your_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-1,3),'/',''),4)
```

WOuld this work for you?

Answer (score -2):

FROMAT(DATETIME, 'dd-MMM') = FROMAT(DATETIME, 'dd-MMM') use any format you want

Comment: What is 'FROMAT'?  Did you mean `FORMAT`?  Also, please have at look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code to learn how to properly format your code.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply